# When to take left and right limit of equation?

Tags: limits

I have problems understanding when to take the left and right limit of an equation. For example,

according to my teacher, you have to take the left and right limit of this equation:
$$ \lim _ {x \to-2} = \ \frac{x}{x^2 + 8 \cdot x + 12}$$

but not this equation:
$$ \lim_{x\to 1} = \ \frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2 - 2 \cdot x + 1}$$

Can anyone explain to my why?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing like 'a limit of equation'. Additionaly I can't see an equation in your question. Could you, please, clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both limits that you have there do not exit. The reason they do not exist is because their one-sided limits are not equal (that's how you prove whether a limit exists or does not exist). In fact, they're so-called [infinite limits](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/InfiniteLimits.aspx) (they do not exist even as infinite limits):

$$
\lim _ {x \to-2} \frac{x}{x^2 + 8 x + 12}=
\lim _ {x \to-2}\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+6)}\implies\\
\lim _ {x \to-2^-} \frac{x}{(x+2)(x+6)}=+\infty,\ \lim _ {x \to-2^+} \frac{x}{(x+2)(x+6)}=-\infty\implies\\
\lim _ {x \to-2^-}\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+6)}\ne\lim _ {x \to-2^+}  \frac{x}{(x+2)(x+6)}\implies\\
\lim _ {x \to-2}\frac{x}{x^2 + 8 x + 12}=DNE.
$$

You do exactly the same procedure for the second limit:

$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2 - 2x + 1}
\lim_{x\to 1}=\frac{(x - 1)(x+1)}{(x-1)^2}=
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x+1}{x-1}\implies\\
\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x+1}{x-1}=-\infty,\ \lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x+1}{x-1}=+\infty\implies\\
\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x+1}{x-1}\ne\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x+1}{x-1}\implies\\
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2 - 2x + 1}=DNE.
$$

So, you do have to consider the two one-sided limits of the second limit in its analysis because that's the way to answer the question about its existence. It does not exist as an infinite limit because the two one-sided limits do not equal the same type of infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$x^2+8x+12=(x+6)(x+2)$$ and $$x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$$
and use that $$\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)^2}$$
and $$\frac{x}{(x+6)(x+2)}$$ and you have to compute the limit in both directions.

Comment: What I understand of this, is that you ALWAYS have to take the left and right limit?

Comment: Yes, this is right.